# Low temperature solder

Tags: soldering

I am soldering LED strips together but I am in a location without access to an electrical outlet.  I am using a battery powered soldering iron but it doesn't get very hot compared to my home soldering iron.  I am having a tough time melting the solder with it and getting it to stick to the pads.  Can you guys recommend a solder that melts at a low temperature?  I have also tried a butane powered iron but it broke after only a few uses so I would prefer to try a new solder before changing the iron.

Comment: Use an inverter and a car battery with a proper soldering iron.

Comment: We cannot recommend low-temperature solder. Especially since they usually contain things that make lead look as harmless as a flower.

Answer (score 2):

Tin-bismuth solder melts at ~140C and is also lead-free. Japanese use it extensively; however since JEDEC is hostile towards it you will have difficulties to source it outside of Asia. SnBi solder paste is available from eBay, expect 2-3 weeks delivery.

If your iron is capable of melting the solder you currently have you may try to help it with another heater. Plain household hotplate will work in a pinch; ones currently sold in the states are cold enough at full power to use with SAC305. If you're using leaded solder start with low setting and advance slowly - and never use this hotplate for cooking food afterwards.

Comment: If the OP doesn't have an outlet, he's unlikely to be able to plug in a hotplate. Maybe a camp stove with a heavy griddle to distribute heat.

Comment: @DoxyLover Almost anything having good thermal mass and two parallel flat surfaces of sufficient size will work, even a brick heated up in a campfire - I'm speaking from experience.